# double click implementaion in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am implementing zooming feature in my application. When i double click on image, the image going to zoom. For single click working fine. but double click not working in mobile but it working in  browser.
I used doubletap, ondblclick and dblclick. these are not working in mobile, but working perfectly in browser.
I'm using phonegap, and tested in android mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After including plugin, double click working, check bellow link for more details.
https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Touch-Events